# What is equivalent of "max depth" in the 'R' package "ranger"?

Tags: r, random-forest

Other random forest tools have the "dial" that limits max depth of splits on a particular branch.

h2o.randomForest has "max_depth", for example.

What is the version of that for "ranger"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the `h2o.randomForest` package, but my general understanding of random forests is that each tree will be grown until a certain minimum number of data points fit into each leaf of the tree.  In other words, a tree will keep splitting until a certain level of classification of each data point has been achieved.  In the standard `randomForest` package, there is a parameter called `nodesize` which controls this:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158583/what-does-node-size-refer-to-in-the-random-forest

The analogous parameter in the `ranger` package seems to be `min.node.size`.  You can compare the information in the link above with the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/index.html) to convince yourself that they are both discussing the same thing.

Comment: max depth is about how many splits between stump and leaf.  It is a control parameter that is used to avoid over-fitting.

Comment: @EngrStudent I don't believe that over fitting is a big concern with random forests.  And in any case the node size gives you the same control over splitting.

Comment: Anything can over-fit.  It is not the largest issue, but if you want tuned performance, then you must tune.  If you limit the number of splits made for a binary tree, then you put an upper bound on compute time.

Comment: My understanding of random forests is that they are relatively not prone to overfitting, but maybe I'm wrong.  In any case, controlling the node size should give you the same control that controlling the number of splits would give you.

Comment: Consider page 24 of this: http://www2.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/014swclass/files/mark.pdf