# set max depth for tuning ranger in random forest tidymodels r

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels, r-ranger

I would like to tune the depth of my random forest to avoid overfitting.  I am using tidymodels and this is my model code.

```
rf_model <- rand_forest(mtry = tune(), 
                        trees = tune(),
                        max.depth = tune()) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity")
```

It gives me an error that:

```
Error in rand_forest(mtry = tune(), trees = tune(), max.depth = tune()): unused argument (max.depth = tune())
```

I also tried tree_depth = tune() from dials documentation, and that gives the same error.

But when I look at ranger documentation, it has max.depth as a parameter. wondering how to tune depth with tidymodels tune.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `max.depth` argument, so like in ranger (see [What is equivalent of "max depth" in the 'R' package "ranger"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291685/what-is-equivalent-of-max-depth-in-the-r-package-ranger) for explanation) the minimum number of nodes can be used instead. This works:

```
rf_model <- rand_forest(mtry = tune(), trees = tune(), min_n = tune()) %>%
    set_mode("classification") %>% set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity")
```

Which produces a valid `rf_model`:

```
> rf_model
Random Forest Model Specification (classification)

Main Arguments:
  mtry = tune()
  trees = tune()
  min_n = tune()

Engine-Specific Arguments:
  importance = impurity

Computational engine: ranger
```